# how to get discord forum tag?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I watched "https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-create-a-post-in-a-forum-channel" which mentioned that the way to obtain Tag is to use ForumChannel#availableTags

But I have been unable to get the tags when adding a new forum. Below is my sample code.

```
discord.on('threadCreate', async (thread) => {
   const cache = discord.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.id === thread.id);
   console.log(thread.guild.channels.guild);
});
```

How do I get the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ThreadChannel#appliedTags](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.13.0/class/ThreadChannel?scrollTo=appliedTags).

```js
discord.on('threadCreate', async (thread) => {
   if (!(thread.parent instanceof ForumChannel)) {
      console.log("Not a forum channel");
   }
   console.log("tags:", thread.appliedTags.map(s => thread.parent.availableTags.find(t => t.id === s)).map(x => x.name).join(","));
});
```

Comment: oh！this is very useful for me！:D